# DirectX using Visual Studio 2012 Express (Windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, express, windows-7, directx

Is it possible to use directx using Virtual Studio 2012 Express on windows 7? Is there anyone who actually uses/used/knows how to use it?

The quote from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx says:

> Make sure that you are using one of the premium Visual Studio SKUs.
>   Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 or Microsoft Visual
>   Studio Express 2013 for Windows won't build Windows 8 and later
>   desktop applications such as the DirectX SDK samples.

It says that some specific samples can't be used by non-premium versions, but how about using it in general?

I don't know how it works but by following tutorial (designed for windows 8) I used the same header files such as "d2d1.h" and "d2d1_1.h" which somehow worked without manually downloading any SDK. The problem was that the created window was frozen and unusable. Then I installed Windows SDK which supposedly contain required libraries, I tried using them but without positive result.

Here's the script I used: http://pastebin.com/xVU4R34m (just in case)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Make sure you have installed the June 2010 DirectX SDK.

The code in the link only creates a window, it doesn't use any DirectX functionality.